# ES screenshot in automated mail

Tags: java, oracle11g, cron, elasticsearch-marvel

As I am new to elasticsearch server, we are using **ES version 1.7.3** with Java 8 and also we are using monitoring tools like marvel, HQ & big-desk to check the cluster health performance and stats of the ES cluster. We also implemented shield for authentication purpose.
But My question is,

**1. How to get an automated email along with screenshot of ES cluster from elasticsearch?
  (or)
2. Is there any other way to get screenshot of ES cluster and sent it to mail by using like cron job?**

Please suggest your ideas

Thanks,

Ganeshbabu R

Comment: For this case You should   use phantom js to get the screenshots

Answer (score 0):

For this case You should   use phantom js to get the screenshots